# jQuery: How to get the input value from an input field made with PHP/CakePHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp

I've tried a couple of things and still can't get the value to be returned correctly. Im using CakePHP 2.0v.

Here is my first input field

```php
echo $this->Form->input('semesterFrom', array(
  'options' => $semesterOptions,
  'empty' => 'Select',
  'label' => false,
  'class' => 'form-control', 
  'name' => 'data[student][semester]'));
```

Here is my second input/select field

```php
echo $this->Form->year('class_yearFrom', date('Y'), 2030, array(
  'empty' => __('Select Year'),
  'class' => 'form-control year',
  'name' => 'data[student][class_year]'));
```

Ive tried the following.

```
var attendanceSemesterValue = app.myGoalForm().find('#StudentSemesterFrom').val(); //also variations of :selected and .text()/.val()
var attendanceYearValue = app.myGoalForm().find('#StudentClassYearFromYear :selected').val();

if (attendanceSemesterValue === "Select" && attendanceYearValue === "Select Year") { 
       var wantedYearValue; 
       wantedYearValue = 0;
      } else {
            wantedYearValue = {
                'semesterFrom': app.myGoalForm().find('#StudentSemesterFrom :selected').val(),
                'yearFrom': app.myGoalForm().find('#StudentClassYearFromYear :selected').val(),
            };
            var studentRangeValue = app.myGoalForm().find('#StudentRange').is(':checked');

            if (studentRangeValue) {
                $.extend(wantedYearValue, {
                    'semesterTo': app.myGoalForm().find('#StudentSemesterTo :selected').text(),
                    'yearTo': app.myGoalForm().find('#StudentClassYearToYear :selected').text(),
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: What value do you get and how do you know it is incorrect?

Comment: Ive added more of what im trying to do with my if statement, but it always returns 0, regardless of my selection.